# DSolveValue not yielding any solution

Tags: differential-equations

I have the laplace equation:

[image]

I also have the following boundary conditions (BC):

`V = 0` when `y = 0`, `V = 0` when `y = a`, `V = Vo(y)` when `x = 0, V-> 0` as `x -> ∞`.

Query(1):
Now I want  to solve this laplace equation with the mentioned boundary conditions. I tried using DSolveValue but I get errors (I was also unsure how to include the last BC). I tried solving it in 2 ways.

Way1:

```
DSolveValue[
  {D[ϕ[x, y], x, x] + D[ϕ[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   ϕ[0, y] == ϕ[x, 0] == 0, 
   ϕ[0, y] == a, ϕ[x, 0] = ∞}, 
  ϕ[x, y], {x, y}]
```

Way2:

```
sol = 
  DSolveValue[
    {D[V[x, y], x, x] + D[V[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
     V[x, 0] == 0, V[x, a] == 0, 
     V[0, y] == Subscript[V, o][y], V[∞, y] -> 0}, 
    V[x, y], {x, y}]
```

I do know there are problems with the way I did it but I'm not sure how to go on from here.

Query(2): After solving this laplace equation how can one get their solution to look like as shown below? I am not getting the connection here.

[image]

Comment: Try: `DSolveValue[{D[V[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[V[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0, 
  V[x, 0] == 0, V[x, a] == 0, V[0, y] == Vo, V[Infinity, y] == 0}, 
 V[x, y], {x, y}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, Vo > 0}]` for me works fine on Mathematica 12.1.1

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk do you get an output of 0?

Comment: I get: $\underset{K[1]=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}-\frac{2 \left(-1+(-1)^{K[1]}\right) e^{-\frac{\pi  x K[1]}{a}}
   \text{Vo} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y K[1]}{a}\right)}{\pi  K[1]}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk you are getting the right output but I'm getting zero for some reason. I'll try to restart mathematica and hopefully i'll get the right output.

Comment: Try restarting Mathematica.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I did many times but for some reason I am not getting the solution shown above. I am using Mathematica 12.0

Comment: I get @MariuszIwaniuk's answer after just a few seconds, using Mathematica Version 12.1.1 on Windows 10.  Try creating a new notebook, pasting his code into  it, and running it.

Comment: I've tried everything so far- restarting,new notebook, giving mathematica some rest. Maybe it's because my mathematica version is different and it can't DSolve to get this output? I am not even getting any error feedback which at least confirmed long ago that the input is 100% correct.